# VBA-Copying data from one worksheet to another. Wrong dates are populated

Tags: vba

```
Worksheets("TnxDump").Range("A" & i & ":V" & i).Copy Worksheets("TnxSales").Range("A" & lastrow & ":V" & lastrow)
```

For dates less than 12th - month and day are interchanged while pasting.
Like 06-Aug-2015 is converting into 08-June-2015

Answer (score 0):

Please can you confirm the format of the dates in the TnxDump worksheet.

Also as a starting point take a look here:
[Excel 2010 - change US dates to UK format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487247/excel-2010-change-us-dates-to-uk-format#)

Comment: @Thomas-Date column is in General Formatting