# Function: Error Sub or Function not defined

Tags: vba, excel

```
Function CountColor(rColor As Range, rSumRange As Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim vResult As Integer
    iCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex

    For Each rCell In rSumRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iCol Then
            vResult = 1
        Else 
            vResult =  0
        End If
    Next rCell 
    CountColor = vResult
End Function
```

I try typing **`"=CountColor(A1, A2)"`** but I always get the error `"Sub or function not defined"` Why is this? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Is this in a workbook module, or worksheet module? It works for me if I place in a Workbook module.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351339/cant-use-vba-functions-in-a-spreadsheet-formula-in-excel-2010

Comment: Sorry, what is the difference between the two? I just inserted a module by right clicking on the project and creating a new module.

Comment: worksheet UDFs should be created in a standard code module **in the same workbook**. Failing that, try giving your UDF an explicit return data type

Comment: That is where it should be.  It should be in a module attached to the workbook in which it is being called.

Comment: I can confirm that the module is in the same workbook as it is the only one open. Note: the function shows up when I type =, but just won't compile

Comment: Does it highlight a specific line when you debug?

Comment: I gave it a return datatype of Integer and didn't help. It's highlighting the first line of code. This code has worked before, so I don't think it has to do with coding.

Comment: Is the workbook/worksheet protected in any way?  Try closing Excel completely, and open a new workbook and add this macro. Does it work then?

Comment: Doesn't work if I open a new workbook. It's strange because I have gotten this code to work before. It might have to do with permissions or whatnot though.

Comment: Are your macros enabled?

Comment: Other macros run fine, just not this function

Comment: Exactly where are you typing `=CountColor(A1, A2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce the error that you are experiencing.

If you use the code as you have it, the result will not be accurate, for example:
`=CountColor(A1,B1:B20)` will only give you a result of 1 or 0 because you are not adding the results together.

If you are just comparing the interior colors, you don't really need to use `interior.colorindex`, just `interior.color` should work, so I changed `iCol as string`

`else` is not required in your if statement.

I also added `Application.volatile` to the code, so it will calculate when the sheet calculates.

```
Function CountColor(rColor As Range, rSumRange As Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iCol As String
    Dim vResult As Integer

    iCol = rColor.Interior.Color
    Application.Volatile

    For Each rCell In rSumRange
        If rCell.Interior.Color = iCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
            '        Else
            '            vResult = 0
        End If
    Next rCell

    CountColor = vResult

End Function
```

Comment: I guess that APplication.volatile did the trick? Not sure, but once I added that, the error stopped being produced. Thanks!

Comment: @user3002486 String is the wrong data type for `iCol`.  `.Color` returns numeric, casting it to String is pointless.  Better to use `Long`