# Excel-VBA function which return value in %age like (.15)

Tags: excel, vba

I create following function and call it from excel by writing `=ratingper(b7,u7)`.
But it returns #NAME?.

```
Function RATINGPER(pvar As String, svar As Double) As Double
    If (svar < 20001 And pvar = "A") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.16
    ElseIf (svar < 20001 And pvar = "B") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.14
    ElseIf (svar < 20001 And pvar = "C") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.12
    ElseIf (svar >= 20001 And svar < 30001 And pvar = "A") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.15
    ElseIf (svar >= 20001 And svar < 30001 And pvar = "B") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.11
    ElseIf (svar >= 20001 And svar < 30001 And pvar = "C") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.9
    ElseIf (svar >= 30001 And svar < 55001 And pvar = "A") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.13
    ElseIf (svar >= 30001 And svar < 55001 And pvar = "B") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.9
    ElseIf (svar >= 30001 And svar < 55001 And pvar = "C") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.7
    ElseIf (svar >= 55001 And pvar = "A") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.11
    ElseIf (svar >= 55001 And pvar = B) Then
        RATINGPER = 0.9
    ElseIf (svar >= 55001 And pvar = "C") Then
        RATINGPER = 0.7
    Else
        RATINGPER = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call VBA function from Excel cells (2010)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351339/how-to-call-vba-function-from-excel-cells-2010)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose no #NAME? would appear if the code were typed in a module.